# MariaDB Master / Slave failover / failback automation

Tags: mariadb, failover, automation

Good day all, I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

I'm working on a new dual data center project, and I'm trying to come up with a plan for failover (for patching and other maintenance) and failback. The databases / data centers will act as Primary / DR. Of course DR would fall into this plan. There is no viable 3rd pop for an arbitrator, so clustering isn't in the cards. Each database will be running MariaDB (10.3 or columnstore).

The plan includes running ProxySQL on each application to handle communication with the database, and failover from that perspective. It's my understanding that it can leverage "READ-ONLY" to recognize which database is primary, which seems intuitive.

On the database side I hope to configure Master/Master replication to ease the transition between data centers, and hope to utilize the read only options to control data flow as mentioned previously. And this is where I'm stuck as I need the process to be as easy as possible so that non-DBA's can facilitate the failover without much interaction.

Is there an out of the box, community (free), utility that can perform the necessary steps to effectively "swap" masters and allow for unattended recovery? If not, can anyone point me toward a sample process/script that might achieve the same results?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Get a package like "MHA".  It is "free".

See also Galera and Orchestrator.